# ckeditor issue : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checkReadOnly' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am facing issue when uploading a file (using drag and drop) into CkEditor. i am getting below errors randomly but not all the times.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checkReadOnly' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setStyle' of null
```

Is there a way to solve these errors?

Thanks in advance.